# Валидация email адреса С#

Tags: c#, email, валидация

Пытаюсь сделать валидацию,не могу разобраться как эта штука работает.При нажатии на кнопку,должен проверяться введенный email в текст бокс.При нажатии на кнопку с пустым текст боксом,выводит меседж из катча. Мои абсурдные попытки:

```
 bool IsValidEmail(string email)
    {
        try
        {
            var addr = new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress(email);
            return addr.Address == email;
            MessageBox.Show("Норм адрес");
        }
        catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Неверный адрес");
            return false;
        }
    }
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string email = textBox1.Text;           
        IsValidEmail(email);
    }
```

Comment: В чем заключается вопрос?

Comment: `При нажатии на кнопку с пустым текст боксом,выводит меседж из катча.`  а вы какой результат ожидаете? [конструктор](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/591bk9e8(v=vs.110).aspx) бросает исключение `ArgumentException`

Comment: Ну так посмотрите, что с чем у вас сравнивается.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Проблема в том, что это будет валидный адрес:`IsValidEmail("sdfeh@dgh.c");`
Я использую сл. конструкцию, возможно поможет вам.

```
    bool isValid(string email)
    {
        string pattern = "[.\\-_a-z0-9]+@([a-z0-9][\\-a-z0-9]+\\.)+[a-z]{2,6}";
        Match isMatch = Regex.Match(email, pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
        return isMatch.Success;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Вангую проблема в том что ТС написал показ мессаджбокса после ретурна. Надо лишь поменять местами:

```
bool IsValidEmail(string email)
{
    try
    {
        var addr = new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress(email);

        if (addr.Address == email) {
            MessageBox.Show("Норм адрес");
            return true;
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Неверный адрес");
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: На какой вопрос вы ответили?